# Do I need to close() both FileReader and BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm reading a local file using a BufferedReader wrapped around a FileReader:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
// read the file
// (error handling snipped)
reader.close();
```

Do I need to `close()` the `FileReader` as well, or will the wrapper handle that?
I've seen code where people do something like this:

```
FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
// read the file
// (error handling snipped)
bReader.close();
fReader.close();
```

This method is called from a servlet, and I'd like to make sure I don't leave any handles open.

Comment: Y'know, you can just read the source for info like this. It's all there in src.zip in the JDK installation directory, or you can read it online at for example http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html

Comment: Telling someone to read the source is worse than saying "RTFM!". And what if the source has a bug; implicitly we want to know what the *correct* behaviour is?

Comment: Well... from this point of view: pointing to API specs isn't any better then. If the source hasn't a bug causing that it does not behave like it is specified in the docs, you cannot rely the docs. So there's no good way to answer such a question.

Comment: @Atmocreations The next maintenance release can cheerfully fix a bug that you rely on if you just look at the source.  You really do need to know what the documented behavior is.  Nothing wrong in looking at the source, of course, but you can't assume the source won't change.  Changing documented behavior is usually a _much_ bigger deal than fixing a bug.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

no.

```
BufferedReader.close()
```

**closes the stream** according to javadoc for [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close--) and [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#close--)

as well as

```
FileReader.close()
```

does.

Comment: Unless the constructor to `BufferedReader` throws an exception. It's cleaner just to close the underlying stream, although you need to watch out for decorators with other resources and buffering.

Comment: The Javadoc does not say whether `BufferedReader.close()` closes the underlying reader. Its description is simply copied from `Reader.close()`. This may be the actual behavior in practice, but it's not documented.

Comment: If the actual behaviour was different, then it should have been documented as such. Otherwise the documentation is useless. The programmer should be able to consider the documentation as complete and specific.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the actual documentation should have been changed or shouldn't have been changed, `Reader#close()`'s javadoc's don't say whether or not it closes it's wrapped Reader or not. All it says related to that is `Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it.` which is not explicit enough to say that it does or does not close the resource. 'Release the resource' may just as well be removing any reference to the resource in the BufferedReader...which would mean the resource is not closed.

Comment: I think the term 'system resource' is explicit maybe a bit technical / old fashioned way to qualify a resource which is not managed by the runtime environment (here the JVM) but by the underlying 'system' (which also manages the JVM's process)

Comment: I have found an official Java code example where they close both the FileReader and the BufferedReader. But why? See second example on this page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 114):

As others have pointed out, you only need to close the outer wrapper.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

There is a very slim chance that this could leak a file handle if the `BufferedReader` constructor threw an exception (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`). If your app is in this state, how careful your clean up needs to be might depend on how critical it is that you don't deprive the OS of resources it might want to allocate to other programs.

The [Closeable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface can be used if a wrapper constructor is likely to fail in Java 5 or 6:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
Closeable resource = reader;
try {
  BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(reader);
  resource = buffered;
  // TODO: input
} finally {
  resource.close();
}
```

Java 7 code should use the *try-with-resources* pattern:

```
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
  // TODO: input
}
```

Comment: "Java 7 code should use the try-with-resources pattern".  Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  This solution was written in '09, so the try-with-resources paradigm should probably be the new recommendation.  Furthemore, it offers a better answer to the OP over the accepted and higher voted answer.

Comment: @tresf just searched for 10 minutes trying to find this answer, I couldn't agree more - showing how to open the Filereader so you can close it later is key

Answer (score 7):

According to BufferedReader source, in this case bReader.close call fReader.close so technically you do not have to call the latter.

Comment: Given that there is documentation explaining how it should be used, you should look at the documentation first – any deviation in the code is a bug.

Answer (score 7):

The source code for [BufferedReader](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedReader.java.html) shows that the underlying is closed when you close the BufferedReader.

Comment: I really want to give this a thumbs up for linking to something concrete, but this only refers to the OpenJDK implementation, and since the JavaDocs are unclear for `Reader#close()`, this does not provide concrete evidence that the Oracle JDK, for example, is implemented in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 7):

After checking the source code, I found that for the example:

```
FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
```

the close() method on **BufferedReader** object would call the abstract close() method of **Reader** class which would ultimately call the implemented method in **InputStreamReader** class, which then closes the **InputStream** object.

So, only bReader.close() is sufficient.

Comment: What the source code shows isn't citable as a reference. It's what the *specification* says, in this case the Javadoc, that can be relied on.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Java 7 you can use [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```

Because the `BufferedReader` instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly. So you don't need to close it yourself in the `finally` statement. (This is also the case with nested resource statements)

This is the recomanded way to work with resources, see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more detailed information

Comment: This is nearly identical to @mcdowell's answer from 2009, which also covers some edge-case issues that could occur.

Answer (score 0):

You Only Need to close the bufferedReader i.e reader.close() and it will work fine .

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but:

BufferReader.java:

```
public BufferedReader(Reader in) {
  this(in, defaultCharBufferSize);
}

(...)

public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (in == null)
            return;
        try {
            in.close();
        } finally {
            in = null;
            cb = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eeeeh that doesn't answer his/her question? She/He asks if it's *necessary* to close FileReader and BufferedReader not an example code.

Comment: @TornaxO7 no, it's not an example code. I just wrote part of java source code. So, if you click on some BufferedReader's function with ctrl/cmd key (depends on IDE) you can see BufferedReader's source code, and you can find that fragment of code.

So, as you can see BufferedReader just close FileReader by itself ('in' is FileReader in this case, so, when you call bufferReader.close() it calls  in.close() inside, exactly in bufferReader.close method)

Answer (score 0):

You **Don't** need to close the wrapped reader/writer.

If you've taken a look at the docs ([`Reader.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close()),[`Writer.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close())), You'll see that in `Reader.close()` it says:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it.

Which just says that it "releases any system resources **associated** with it". Even though it doesn't confirm.. it gives you a nudge to start looking deeper. and if you go to `Writer.close()` it only states that it closes itself.

In such cases, we refer to [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes) to take a look at the source code.

At BufferedWriter [Line 265](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#l265) you'll see `out.close()`. So it's not closing itself.. It's something else. If you search the class for occurences of "`out`" you'll notice that in the constructor at [Line 87](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#l87) that `out` is the writer the class wraps where it calls another constructor and then assigning `out` parameter to it's own `out` variable..

So.. What about others? You can see similar code at [BufferedReader Line 514](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java#l514), [BufferedInputStream Line 468](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java#l468) and [InputStreamReader Line 199](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/io/InputStreamReader.java#l199). Others i don't know but this should be enough to assume that they do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close only the `BufferedReader` in your scenario.

As others have pointed out, the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close()) are ambiguous.  Using the try-with-resources block is the best approach when you want `close` to be called right away, but it doesn't work if you need to keep the reader open (e.g. a class that has a method that returns a stream which uses an underlying reader--it would generally be the caller's responsibility to call `close` there).

If you don't have access to the source code and want to see whether your reader and JVM calls `close` on the various readers and streams in your situation, you could override the `close` method as a simple test.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/home/example/test.txt");

InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path.toFile()) {
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("FileInputStream::close()");
        super.close();
    }
};
Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, Charsets.UTF_8) {
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("InputStreamReader::close()");
        super.close();
    }
};
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader) {
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("BufferedReader::close()");
        super.close();
    }
};

bufferedReader.close();
```

When you run the above, you'll see something very similar to:

```
BufferedReader::close()
InputStreamReader::close()
FileInputStream::close()
```

Since there is no explicit specification written in the JavaDoc, we can't be certain of the behavior across all JVMs.  However, most of readers/streams seem to follow the above pattern (e.g. you can add a `GZIPInputStream` to the above example and see that `GZIPInputStream::close()` also gets called).