# Lucene Custom Scoring

Tags: java, lucene, scoring

I want to make a lucene custom scoring function that takes a value stored in a document and add it to the final score.

I already figured out how to add a value to the scoring function , but I can't manage to get a stored value of a document into the method.

```
 class CustomizedScoreProvider extends CustomScoreProvider {

    public CustomizedScoreProvider(LeafReaderContext reader) {
            super(reader);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    public  float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore,float valSrcScores[]){

     try {

         subQueryScore+=4; \\ I only added this for testing , 
     } catch(Exception e) { \\ I want to add a value that is stored in a field of a document
         e.printStackTrace();
            }
    return subQueryScore;
             }
    }

class CustomizedScoreQuery extends CustomScoreQuery{


public CustomizedScoreQuery(Query subQuery,IndexReader ireader) {
        super(subQuery);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
public CustomizedScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider (LeafReaderContext reader){
    CustomizedScoreProvider i=new CustomizedScoreProvider(reader);
     return (i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you , but I already solved the problem, with the index reader I searched for the file, then I extracted the value of the field I wanted to use.

```
class CustomizedScoreProvider extends CustomScoreProvider {
private LeafReaderContext context;
public CustomizedScoreProvider(LeafReaderContext reader) {
        super(reader);
        this.context= reader;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public  float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore,float valSrcScores[]) throws IOException{

    Document Social=context.reader().document(doc);
     IndexableField i= Social.getField("soc");// the field I wanted to extract
     float k= (float)i.numericValue();
     subQueryScore+=k;

return subQueryScore;
         }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understood what you are trying to do, then you need to open a file (your "document") and parse a float.

Here it is explained how to open a file and get it's contents in several different ways:
[How to open a txt file and read numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806062/how-to-open-a-txt-file-and-read-numbers-in-java)

Note that you will need `Float.parseFloat(String s)` instead of `Integer.parseInt(String s)`.