# closing an buffer reader is compulsory

Tags: java

I am trying an example from 
http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml
in the example the `BufferReader` is not closed is that necessary to close the `BufferReader`or not? Please explain.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    // Print the content on the console
    System.out.println (strLine);
}
//Close the input stream
in.close();
```

Comment: This might be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. Unfortunately examples like this get copied again and again so can you can remove it from your example. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: Don't use code from rose india.  It is surprising how often it is wrong or poor quality code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Always close streams.** It's a good habit which helps you to avoid some odd behaviour. Calling `close()` method also calls `flush()` so you don't have do this manually.

The best place where to close streams is probably in a `finally` block. If you have it like in your example and an exception occurs before the `in.close()` line, the stream won't be closed.

And if you have chained streams, you can only close the last one and all before it are closed too. This means `br.close()` in your example - not `in.close()`;

**Example**

```
try {
    // do something with streams
} catch (IOException e) {
    // process exception - log, wrap into your runtime, whatever you want to...
} finally {
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        // error - log it at least
    } 
}
```

Alternatively you can use [closeQuietly(java.io.InputStream)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream) in Apache Commons library.

Answer (score 6):

From the perspective of resource leak prevention, it is not strictly necessary to close a wrapper stream if you've also closed the stream that it wraps.  However, closing the wrapped stream may result in stuff getting lost (specifically in the output case), so it is better to close (just) the wrapper, and rely on documented behavior that the closing the wrapper closes the wrapped stream too.  (That is certainly true for the standard I/O wrapper classes!)

---

Like Peter Lawrey, I question the wisdom of relying on "Rose India" examples.  For instance, this one has two more obvious mistakes in it that no half-decent Java programmer should make:

- The stream is not closed in a `finally` block.  If any exception is thrown between opening and closing, the `in.close()` statement won't be executed, and the application will leak an open file descriptor.  Do that too often and your application will start throwing unexpected `IOException`s.
- The DataInputStream in the chain serves no useful purpose.  Instead, they should use `fstream` as the parameter for the `InputStreamReader`.  Or better still, use `FileReader`.

---

Finally, here is a corrected version of the example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("textfile.txt"));
try {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} finally {
    // Close the reader stack.
    br.close();
}
```

or using Java 7's "try with resource":

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("textfile.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        // Print the content on the console
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if an exception occurs when initializing the BufferedReader ? The FileReader will still be open.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the code in my answer, yes it will.  Look at the BufferedReader source code.  However, for that constructor, the only plausible exception is OOME.

Answer (score 0):

Since the underlying stream is closed, it is not absolutely necessary to close `BufferedReader`, even though it is a good practice to close ALL `Closeable`s in reverse order (relative to the order they were opened in.)