# When I close a BufferedInputStream, is the underlying InputStream also closed?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

```
InputStream in = SomeClass.getInputStream(...);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);

try {
    // read data from bis
} finally {
    bis.close();
    in.close();    
}
```

The javadoc for `BufferedInputStream.close()` doesn't mention whether or not the underlying stream is closed:

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated
>   with the stream. Once the stream has been closed, further read(),
>   available(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException.
>   Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

Is the explicit call to `in.close()` necessary, or should it be closed by the call to `bis.close()`?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Yeeeeesssss. Seriously, look at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java.html#472

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the source code of [BufferedInputStream](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java#l483) :

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer;
    while ( (buffer = buf) != null) {
        if (bufUpdater.compareAndSet(this, buffer, null)) {
            InputStream input = in;
            in = null;
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            return;
        }
        // Else retry in case a new buf was CASed in fill()
    }
}
```

So the answer would be : YES

Answer (score 9):

BufferedInputStream doesn't hold any system resources itself; it simply wraps around an InputStream which holds those resources. Therefore the BufferedInputStream forwards the close operation onto the wrapped InputStream which will then release its resources.

Answer (score 7):

When you close a BufferedInputStream, the underlying InputStream is indeed also closed. :)

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @GrahamBorland you can simply look the source code of Java

Comment: Also, that would be my reading of "releases any system resources associated with the stream". But yeah, they could be more explicit.

Comment: @GrahamBorland There are dozens of similar questions on stackoverflow already. I'll link a few: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199142/closing-bufferedreader-and-inputstreamreader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263926/closing-inputstreams-in-java

Comment: @rhobincu Thanks, I couldn't find any when I searched. Those all refer to `Reader`s rather than `InputStream`s but they're close enough I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The underlying stream will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Java implementation

```
/**
 * Closes this input stream and releases any system resources
 * associated with the stream.
 * Once the stream has been closed, further read(), available(), reset(),
 * or skip() invocations will throw an IOException.
 * Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.
 *
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer;
    while ( (buffer = buf) != null) {
        if (bufUpdater.compareAndSet(this, buffer, null)) {
            InputStream input = in;
            in = null;
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            return;
        }
        // Else retry in case a new buf was CASed in fill()
    }
}
```

So, the stream will be closed