# Java: Close after returning BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, resources, inputstream

I am planning a function that creates and returns an `InputStream` that in turn reads from another `InputStream` because the initialization of that `InputStream` is not trivial and I would like to use it in multiple places. Consider this simple example:

```
private static InputStream openStream() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("/etc/passwd");
    InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(path);
    return new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
}
```

I will use this function as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (InputStream stream = openStream()) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes;
        while ((numBytes = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            System.out.printf("Just read %d bytes from stream!%n", numBytes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I am concerned that closing the `BufferedInputStream` in this example will not close the `InputStream` inside it. Will this lead to orphaned file handles and memory leaks if called multiple times? What is a better solution for this?

A simple solution I could think of is to define a closable container class and put both input streams into that class. When calling `close()`, this class would simply close all its open handles.

```
class StreamContainer implements Closeable {

    private final InputStream[] inputStreams;

    public StreamContainer(InputStream... inputStreams) {
        this.inputStreams = inputStreams;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        for (InputStream inputStream : this.inputStreams) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I suppose, there might be a better solution, built-in mechanic or development pattern. Or maybe these constructs should be avoided?

Comment: I think it will get closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263926/closing-inputstreams-in-java. "By convention, wrapper streams (which wrap existing streams) close the underlying stream when they are closed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this cases you should read the code source of the `BufferedInputStream`, this is the close definition

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    while(true) {
        byte[] buffer;
        if ((buffer = this.buf) != null) {
            if (!U.compareAndSetObject(this, BUF_OFFSET, buffer, (Object)null)) {
                continue;
            }

            InputStream input = this.in;
            this.in = null;
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
            }

            return;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see when closing the BufferedInputStream, the underlying input stream is closed as well.

And this is the documentation of close:

> public void close() throws IOException
> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream. Once the
> stream has been closed, further read(), available(), reset(), or
> skip() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a previously
> closed stream has no effect.

Comment: Thanks. I should have read the documentation first. I just saw many code examples in which the contained input stream was closed before the containing one, so I assumed that `BufferedInputStream` would not close its contained input stream.