# Can BufferedReader be closed automatically in Java

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I was getting an warning on resource leak (BufferedReader was not closed). I fixed that by putting a close statement before the Return statement and ran the program. But I got an NullPointerException. My question is can it be closed automatically (somehow) when file reading was done. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203291/what-happens-to-a-bufferedreader-that-doesnt-get-closed-within-a-callable-call) looks similar though.

Comment: `IOUtils.closeQuietly()` inside a `finally`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/java7-try-with-resources-statement-advantage

Comment: I fixed my code but just curious to know if a resource can get closed automatically somehow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use try-with-resources Java 7 feature:

```
try(BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(...)) {
     ...
}
```

it will be closed automatically when exiting block

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Interesting! Thanks @Evgeniy

Answer (score 2):

Prior java 7 the general pattern of closable IO resources was like the following:

```
Resource r = null; // either stream, reader, writer etc
try { 
    r = ... // create resource
    use resource r
} catch(IOException e) {
   // some code
} finally {
    if (r != null) {
         r.close();
    }
}
```

The resource is used in `finally` block that guarantees that it will be closed whether the operation is done successfully or failed. `null`-check is needed to prevent NPE if `IOException` was thrown while creating the resource.

Java 7 introduced new syntax that creates illusion that the resource is closed "automatically":

```
try (
    Resource r = // create resource
){ 
    use resource r
} catch(IOException e) {
   // some code
}
```

`finally` block is actually added here automatically by compiler.

I hope this answers your question about automatic closing of `BufferedReader`.