# How to escape a line that starts with a special character while reading files in java

Tags: java, file, io, escaping

Suppose a file contains the following lines:

```
#Do
#not
#use
#these
#lines.

Use
these.
```

My aim is to read only those lines which does not start with `#`. How this can be optimally done in Java?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [documentation of the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BufferedReader.readLine() return a String. you could check if that line starts with `#` using string.startsWith()

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("file1.txt");
    BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line="";
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        if(!line.startsWith("#")){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider using try-finally to prevent resource leak (details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1388772/490018).

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you want to accumulate the lines (of course you can do everything with each line).

```
String filePath = "somePath\\lines.txt";

// Lines accumulator.
ArrayList<String> filteredLines = new ArrayList<String>();

BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
try {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Line filtering. Please note that empty lines
        // will match this criteria!
        if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
            filteredLines.add(line);
        }
    }
}
finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null)
        bufferedReader.close();
}
```

Using Java 7 **try-with-resources** statement:

```
String filePath = "somePath\\lines.txt";
ArrayList<String> filteredLines = new ArrayList<String>();

try (Reader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {

    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.startsWith("#"))
            filteredLines.add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.startsWith()` method. in your case you would use 
`if(!myString.startsWith("#"))
{
  //some code here
}`

Comment: `String` "#" instead of `char`

Comment: While you're at it, it's `startsWith`, not `StartsWith`. All Java methods start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry, you're talkin to a c# guy here