# In Java: "Too many open files" error when reading from a network path

Tags: java, networking, io

I have the code below, which simply reads all the files from a folder. There are 20,000 files in this folder. The code works good on a local folder (`d:/files`), but fails on a network path (`//robot/files`) after reading about 1,000 - 2,000 files.

**Update**: the folders are copies of each other.

What causes this problem and how to fix it?

```
package cef_debug;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String folder = args[0];
        File[] files = (new File(folder)).listFiles();
        String line;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i]));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            }
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when reading from a network path (`//robot/files`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:55)
        at cef_debug.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

Line 12 is the line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i]));
```

Comment: Instead of just throwing away exceptions and leaving connection in unkownstate, I would add try/catch/finally make sure all open connections are closed.

Comment: inside your loop you should be closing all resources. I think you are leaving the FileReader open because you are only closing the BufferedReader... you should try catch finally and in finally close those resources.

Comment: @chrislhardin according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader this is not true. Good questing, imho.

Comment: @chrislhardin, here is the description of close() of BufferedReader from documantation: "Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it."

Comment: What happens if you change your call to `File[] files = (new File(folder)).listFiles();` to `String[] files = (new File(folder)).list();`? Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Add a small delay after `br.close();` and see what happens.

Comment: @Laf, I checked it, and get exactly the same error on network path only.

Comment: @Banthar, I added `Thread.sleep(10);` after `br.close();`. No effect. BTW, the two servers are standing one on the other and connected with 1Gb.

Comment: Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Check which files are open.

Comment: @Serg can you add your windows version + java version

Comment: This looks definitely like a bug in either Java or the operating systems' network code. I'd try to debug into the `close()` and see what happens. Anyway, you should make sure you have the latest Java version installed.

Comment: @eis, on both servers the java is jdk1.6.0_23, and windows 7

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this with jdk7u9. Maybe try this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [documented bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4189011) for some java versions and some file opens to hit a limit of 2035. It is possible that you might've just hit that.

From the comments:

> To clarify the issue, on win32 system there are three  ways to open a
> file:
>
> 1: Using Win32 API
>
> 2: Using MFC class framework lib.
>
> 3: using C-Library API (open() and fopen())
>
> Other than the third option, i.e. option 1 and 2 have practically no
> limitation in opening number of files. The third method is restricted
> (for the reason not known to me) to open only approx. 2035 files. That
> is why MS JVM is able to open unlimited (practically) files, but SUN
> JVM  fails after 2035 files (my guess is it is using 3rd method to
> open file).

Now, this is an old issue fixed quite some time ago, but it is possible that they would be using the same function on *network* access, where the bug could still exist.

Even *without* closing the handle or the stream, windows should be able to open >10000 file handles and keep them open, as demonstrated by this test code in the bug comments:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

// if run with "java maxfiles 10000", will create 10k files in the current folder
public class maxfiles
{
    static int count = 0;
    static List files = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < Integer.parseInt(args[0]); n++) {
            File f = new File("file" + count++);
            //save ref, so not gc'ed
            files.add(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
        }
        Iterator it = files.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PrintStream out = ( PrintStream) it.next();
            out.println("foo");
            out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("current files open: " + files.size());
    } //~main
}
```

You could test running it on the network share, and report a bug if it fails. You could also try with a different JDK. At least with [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) source, I couldn't see any other calls except WinAPI calls, so I'd try if the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Also, I bet the new Java 7 file API might also perform better.

Comment: @eis, actually as you see in the code, I don't open more than one file simultaneously (and I don't wish to). For some reason I receive the error as if I do. I suspect that the `close()` releases the thread before it actually closes the file, so the `new BufferedReader()` begins before closing the last file.

Comment: @Serg It is possible that it doesn't matterif it's simultanious or not. but I would suggest you test a) different JDK and b) having the read on a separate method, getting file name as a parameter, so you can isolate if it's a gc issue (it's easier for the JVM to do gc if the reader is only defined in a separate method)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
package cef_debug;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String folder = args[0];
        File[] files = (new File(folder)).listFiles();
        String line;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i]));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null){
                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that won't compile, as you've defined `br` within your try block

Comment: Written without compiling to check, I'm sure the OP get's the point