# Closing a BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

If I invoke a BufferedReader the following way:

```
Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
```

Will the JVM know to automatically close it when not in use? If not, how do I go about closing it?

Comment: Careful closing any `InputStream` or `Reader` that wraps `System.in`. That will be closed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using java 7 or greater and your code is in `try catch resource` block, then it is [`Auto closes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

If in below versions you have to close with [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close%28%29). For that you have to change your current way of using and get the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Don't chain them, declare and assign variables, then close it after the usage.

```
InputStreamReader isReader;
BufferedReader bfReader;
try {
     isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
     bfReader = new BufferedReader(isReader).readLine();
} catch (Exception e) {
// handle as per the requirement.
} finally {
    bfReader.close();
}
```

If you use java 7, then, if you defined withing the try clause, then those will auto closable. Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) for more details

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is as an object that must be closed
>   after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources
>   statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the
>   statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which
>   includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as
>   a resource.

Comment: It says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader?rq=1) that closing the BufferedReader would close the InputStreamReader as well.

Comment: Indeed it does. 1) You should only close the outside decorator of this type, here the BufferedReader. 2) Surely you're not recommending that catch blocks be ignored, are you? 3) I usually check for null before closing. Please remember that newbies will take your code literally, including empty catch blocks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : It should be handle Question owner as per his requirement.