# Initialize as Argument or Separate?

Tags: java

Which is more efficient or SAFE regarding memory and all ?

```
classA A = new classA();
classB B = new classB(A);
A.dispose();
```

or

```
classB B = new classB(new classA());
```

Comment: I think it's generally a fishy idea to have the caller call A.dispose() when A is "passed off to" the constructor of B, because the general reason to pass A to B's constructor is to store it for later use. Consider having B "own" A and "dispose" A as appropriate. Many of the [Java IO wrapper classes work this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader): most streams will automatically "close" (or "dispose") the underlying source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THERE IS NO DIFFERENCE.

**Example :**

Consider the following code.

```
class A {
}

class B {
    public B(A a) {

    }
}

class  Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b1 = new B(a);

        B b2 = new B(new A());
    }
}
```

If you will see the compiled code below you will find that java compiler includes two `invokespecial` and two `new` instructions, so each time a separate Object of class `A` will be created and stored in heap, Reference of that object will be passed as parameter to constructor of class `B`.

**Compiled code :**

```
class Test extends java.lang.Object{
Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new         #2; //class A                   
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method A."<init>":()V     
   7:   astore_1
   8:   new         #4; //class B                   
   11:  dup
   12:  aload_1
   13:  invokespecial   #5; //Method B."<init>":(LA;)V  
   16:  astore_2
   17:  new         #4; //class B                  
   20:  dup
   21:  new         #2; //class A                  
   24:  dup
   25:  invokespecial   #3; //Method A."<init>":()V    
   28:  invokespecial   #5; //Method B."<init>":(LA;)V 
   31:  astore_3
   32:  return

}
```

You can see that just execution order is changed.

**Side Note :**

- `invokespecial` JVM instruction is used to invoke constructor (Instance initialization method) of
  class.
- `new` is used to create a new instance of class.
- `<init>` is a special name of constructor supplied by compiler, and it is not a valid java identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are never going to use `ClassA A` then there is no point in defining it. As for `efficient or SAFE regarding memory and all` - no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Do not create ClassA A = new ClassA();
because you are not using it. unnecessarily you are giving work for heap.
directly write
classB B = new classB(new classA());
hope this will helps you

Comment: "you are giving work for heap"...can you explain this ?